# asp.NET MVC4 using partial views in partial views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Let's assume I have 3 custom controllers: AController, BController and CControler and one default HomeController. Each of the first three controllers have a very unique partial view for them, let's name them APartial, BPartial, CPartial and these are invoked with AFunction, BFunction and CFunction with a template looking like:

```
public ActionResult XFunction
{
    /*put some data into a ViewBag*/
    return PartialView("XPartial");
}
```

Respectivelly, APartial.cshtml, BPartial.cshtml, CPartial.cshtml are in the `Shared` folder.
What is the best way to return all three views in one page when HomeController's Index (ActionResult method) is called. I tried rendering each like:

```
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "XFunction");
    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
}
```

then putting each into ViewBag's dynamic variables, but I have a feeling there has to be a way nicer solution.

Comment: can't you just put all three of them in a view?

Comment: No, I would like to reuse them in other places.

Comment: I mean in another view that renders all three partials like so: @Html.Partial('partialview1')   @Html.Partial('partialview2')   @Html.Partial('partialview3')

Comment: The problem is, I am calling this async and I cannot write `@Html.Partial`, because I replace my main div with the result, so either: I cannot do that OR I overlooked being able to call `@Html.Partial` inside my Home/Index.cshtml. I am going to try that. I'll let you know asap.

Comment: RenderAction did the trick, but it was basically the same idea as you told, I think :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RenderAction in your view. Good explanation is here: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/

Comment: RenderAction did the trick. Thanks for saving me!!! :) Now it is so much easier to handle everything.